# Автоматизировать добавление кнопок в телеграмм бот

Tags: python, telebot

весь вечер ломал голову как это сделать, так и не понял.

Как сделать чтобы кнопки(markup) добавлялись автоматически. Допустим мне нужно добавить новый товар в бота либо удалить его. Как это сделать?

Comment: И что тут автоматического?

Comment: И покажите код, как Вы пытались это сделать